# Correct inner point based on reference frame points

Tags: vectors

I have 5 points (represented as vectors): $\bar{a}$, $\bar{b}$, $\bar{c}$, $\bar{d}$, and $\bar{p}$.

($\bar{a}$, $\bar{b}$, $\bar{c}$, $\bar{d}$) make up a 'frame' and $\bar{p}$ is a point inside the frame.

I want to be able to translate the frame points into a square/rectangle formation ($\bar{a}$, $\bar{b}$, $\bar{c}$, $\bar{d}$ -> $\bar{a'}$, $\bar{b'}$, $\bar{c'}$, $\bar{d'}$) and get a corrected point $\bar{p'}$ that is $\bar{p}$ adjusted by the translation of the frame points.

Here is an image to visualize, in this situation I would know $\bar{a}$, $\bar{b}$, $\bar{c}$, $\bar{d}$, $\bar{a'}$, $\bar{b'}$, $\bar{c'}$, $\bar{d'}$ and $\bar{p}$ and would be trying to find $\bar{p'}$:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTBZB.png)

Can someone walk me through the process to do this or direct me to a good source?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a straightforward application of affine transformations:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Can you help me understand how I would apply affine transformations in this case? To clarify, I know the positions of 4 points and I have 4 corresponding points that I want to translate to, however, it could be the case that 3 of the corresponding points are the same and only one is different. How could I create a transformation matrix given that information?